# Is Kotlin's type system Turing complete?

Tags: type-systems, genetic-programming

Java's type system is [Turing complete](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.05274). For whatever reason, I was under the impression that Kotlin's type system (for concreteness, let's say the latest version of the language -- `1.5.30`) was *not* Turing complete.

I'm not sure exactly where I got this impression, but this leads to the question: Is Kotlin's type system Turing complete? Specifically, is it Turing complete by the same mechanism used in the paper linked above?

Towards the end of this paper, the author says:

> Does the reduction from Section 5 apply to other languages like
> C] and Scala? No. Both of them adopted the recursive–expansive
> restriction of (Viroli 2000), as recommended by (Kennedy and
> Pierce 2007). Roughly, this restriction is a syntactic check that
> succeeds if and only if our Turing tapes are bounded.

I could not find the referenced paper outside of a pay-wall, so I cannot say exactly what this restriction is, but it leads to the question: Does Kotlin have this restriction, thus not making Kotlin's type system Turing complete (by the same mechanism as Java)?

Comment: No, it's not like java: the specifications of the language (https://kotlinlang.org/spec/introduction.html) say that the parametric polymorphism is bounded.

Comment: @Marzio De Biasi Does that not just mean that generic parameters can be bound by subtype constraints? That's the impression I get here -- and Java has that as well. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#:~:text=In%20type%20theory%2C%20bounded%20quantification,of%20parametric%20polymorphism%20with%20subtyping.

Comment: In fact, Java is listed as an example.